# VB.NET Connection string (Web.Config, App.Config)

Tags: vb.net, connection-string

Really having an annoying time with connection strings.

I have two projects together in a single solution. A Web forms application acting as the presentation layer, and a class library supporting it which will send and receive data from a database.

-- The Employee Class within the Class Library Project --

```
Friend Class Employee

Public Function GetEmployees() As DataSet

    Dim DBConnection As New SqlConnection(My_ConnectionString)
    Dim MyAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter("exec getEmployees", DBConnection)

    Dim EmployeeInfo As DataSet
    MyAdapter.Fill(EmployeeInfo, "EmployeeInfo")

    Return EmployeeInfo

End Function

End Class
```

Currently the application is telling me it cannot access "My_ConnectionString" which I have attempted to store within a config file for quick repeated access:

```
<configuration>

<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"  />
</system.web>

 <connectionStrings>
   <add name="My_ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=My_DB;Integrated Security=True;"/>
 </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

The web.config is part of the web form project and not the class library, are these projects unable to 'talk' to each other? Do I need to add a web / app config file to the class library to store a connection string within that project?

Comment: From your code it looks like you're trying to use `My_ConnectionString` to retrieve the value from your config file.  If that is correct, that will not work - you need to retrieve it from the config file in a manner similar to @G. Stoynev's answer below.

Comment: this might be useful http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Not clear where `My_ConnectionString` is coming from in your example, but try this

`System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("My_ConnectionString").ConnectionString`

like this

```
Dim DBConnection As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("My_ConnectionString").ConnectionString)
```

Comment: You can also add a reference to `System.Configuration`, import it with `Imports System.Configuration` and then access it with the shorter `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("My_ConnectionString").ConnectionString`.

Comment: I would also suggest using a `Using` block to ensure the connection is properly disposed of.

Comment: 'ConfigurationManager' is not a member of 'Configuration'

I feel like I've made a mistake somewhere...

Comment: @Corgalas - Did you add a reference to System.Configuration in your project (the DLL) and add an `Imports System.Configuration` statement?

Comment: Forgot the add the reference to the project. Thanks Tim!

Comment: this answer solved my problem and I think this is the best practice to declare connection sting by it's name. it helps migration process

Comment: I have never understood why System.Configuration isn't included by default.

Answer (score 5):

If it's a .mdf database and the connection string was saved when it was created, you should be able to access it via:

```
    Dim cn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.DatabaseNameConnectionString)
```

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

**Connection in APPConfig**

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.1.25;Initial Catalog=Login;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=example.com"   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**In Class.Cs**

```
public string ConnectionString
{
    get
    {
        return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function connectDB() As OleDbConnection

        Dim Con As New OleDbConnection
        'Con.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=" & DBNAME & ";Data Source=" & DBSERVER & ";Pwd=" & DBPWD & ""
        Con.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;Data Source=DBSERVER-TOSH;User ID=Sa;Pwd= & DBPWD"
        Try
            Con.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            showMessage(ex)
        End Try
        Return Con
    End Function
```

Comment: Would you please add some explanation to your code? Thanks!

Comment: This connection string has hard coded entries,it's not getting them from the .config. What if you need to point to a different server? With this code the application would need deploying with the changes. With .config it can be changed in the background

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this still is an issue, but i prefere just to use the My.Settings in my code.

Visual Studio generates a simple class with functions for reading settings from the app.config file.

You can simply access it using My.Settings.ConnectionString.

```
    Using Context As New Data.Context.DataClasses()
        Context.Connection.ConnectionString = My.Settings.ConnectionString
    End Using
```