# Where do I get connection string information?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

How can I get the vb.net 2010 connection string using the vb.net 2010 **IDE**?

```
dbprovider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
dbsource = "Data Source = C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.mdb"
con.ConnectionString = dbprovider & dbsource
con.Open()
```

I have this connection string but I don't know where they get the provider.

Comment: By saying "they", you mean whom?

Comment: I get the dbprovider in internet. Because don't know how to get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection string [may reside in app.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446175/vb-net-connection-string-web-config-app-config).

If you are more interested in how you construct a connection string, see [this website](http://www.connectionstrings.com/).

In your example, the backend is [Access-2000](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2000/).