# Vb.Net setting connection in Module

Tags: vb.net, module, database-connection, connection-string

I'm creating a new Vb.Net project and I'm looking to create a module that will fire up when project is run so that the connection is set. I created a new module called Connection and placed the following code there...

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Module Connection
    Sub main()
        Dim sConnection As String = "Data Source=Van;Initial Catalog=OP;User ID=userid;Password=password"
    End Sub
End Module
```

And now in my Form1 I added the SQLConnection component and attempt to do something like this....

```
Using Con as New SQLConnection(sConnection)
```

'but this does not seem to work. The connection string works properly since it's fully working if I include it in the form itself.

Any particular reason why this is happening? Also, say I have 30 forms in the app, do I need to add the SqlConnection component to each form that will need to talk to the DB?

Comment: get rid of the Sub Main and just declare it as `Friend SQLConnStr As String = "Data Source=Van;Initial Catalog=OP;User ID=userid;Password=password"`  Note: Modules do not "fire up" or run and WHERE a variable is declared determines its Scope - your will only exist in that method.  [More about Scope](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33249045/1070452)  ...and we dont do Hungarian notation in NET (sConnection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Main()" is a function. 
And you declared a local variable "sConnection".

Your Form is another class.

**A class can access only its members, global members or global static members (or some friend scenarios like C++).**

Take out that declaration from "Main", either declare in the scope of your Form or declare it as a global variable, where your form can access.

Or put your connection string in a config file and read from it. (easy to configure at later point of time.)

Comment: Since I might need to communicate with the DB in every form, do I have to add the SqlConnection component in all my forms?

Comment: Write the connection string in app.cpnfig and access from there in every form. It is easy.  Refer below link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446175/vb-net-connection-string-web-config-app-config